# Solving recurrence relation in form of $f(n)=f(n-1)+K-n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I asked a question (now deleted) on finding a relation between $$4,10,15,\cdots$$

I studied a little about recurrence relation and solving them. For the above sequence I observed that

$$f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 4, & \textrm{if}\ n=1, \\  f(n-1)+8-n, & \textrm{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

I looked up in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) about methods of solving recurrence relations but I was not able to determine which one is related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$f(n+1)-f(n)=K-(n+1),$$
we have, for $n\ge 2$, 
$$\begin{align}f(n)&=f(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(K-(i+1))\\&=4+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}((K-1)-i)\\&=4+(K-1)(n-1)-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}.\end{align}$$
Note that this holds for $n=1$.

So, for your case, setting $K=8$ gives you
$$f(n)=4+(8-1)(n-1)-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}=\frac{-n^2+15n-6}{2}\ \ (n\ge 1).$$